# Installing MySql with using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, installation

i am building a server using nodejs and mySql

i downloaded mySql from 
    http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
and i downloaded nodejs from 
    http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.6/node-v0.6.6.msi

and when i go via the cmd to 
    C:\program files\nodejs

and type in 
    npm install mysql

i get a huge error msg:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install mysql
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, permission denied 'C:\Program Files\nodejs'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mysql"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-beta-4
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, permission denied 'C:\Program Files\nodejs'
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, permission denied 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mysql"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-beta-4
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, permission denied 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

does anyone know the problem?

thanx allot in advanced..

Comment: Try running cmd as administrator. Right click -> Run as admin

Comment: do you have same errors if you install into folder which does not have whitespaces in the path?

Answer (score 0):

dude you need to turn your internet UP before installing MySql....

it will download mysql drivers to node

and yeah may be you ll need Admin rights...

and thanx i installed by seeing your command onlt

blah blah /nodejs> npm install mysql